# Clarification on sessions CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Recently I have been working on 2 different CodeIgniter projects on my personal machine, and I encountered a problem.

If I were to run both projects at the same time in my browser, and both projects were to use sessions together, one of the sessions tend to time out really quickly. (Like within 3-10 seconds)

Initially I thought I may have some logic error, until I noticed that as long as I only run 1 project at a time, this problem cease to exist. Hence, I suspected that one can not run 2 different projects together. Is that correct?

If that is the case, would that mean that if I were to place 2 projects in the same server, this problem would exist too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to your session settings in CI (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).
This can be set in `application/config/config.php`. Just change values of `$config['sess_cookie_name']` to be different in both CI apps.